# code says that the value I'm trying to access at a particular index from a database returns null even if there is a value

Tags: database, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Code won't access value within a database not sure why since the code detects the snapshot just fine. Clicking the button created here just outputs this

```
E/flutter (  640): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
E/flutter (  640):
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Text('This Works!'),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('chats/MTIH4O2WFPWDvCso107p/messages')
              .snapshots()
              .listen((data) {
            //print(data.toString());
            print(data.docs[0]['text']);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried getting results by reading the documentation but from what I understand reading the documentation the line "data.docs[0]['text']" should return a value and not be empty/null

My doc:

[image]

Comment: Please post the code and error as *text* rather than as an image.

Comment: Have you logged the size of `data.docs`, and what fields *are* actually in `data.docs[0]` if it exists? (Currently we can't tell whether there's no document at all, or whether it exists but without the field you expected.)

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: I'm not a Flutter developer, so I don't know. Maybe you can use a debugger, maybe you can print `data.docs.size()` or something like that. But I can't believe it's *very* hard to find that out - and this is the sort of diagnostic process you should always go through.

Comment: Ok so I did try and determine what the size/length of data and data.docs. data.docs doesn't have a size function but it does have a length function. While data has a size function. Both results are zero even though there should be at least one string value in the database.

Comment: If `data.docs.length()` is zero, then it's really not picking up your document. I suggest try to fetch it directly by complete document name (`FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(...).get()`) for now. You can see the complete document name in the Firestore console.

Comment: Show as an example how data is structured in the object

Comment: This is what my database currently looks like.
https://imgur.com/a/QbkRDRH

Answer (score 0):

Your code loads data from:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('chats/MTIH4O2WFPWDvCso107p/messages')
```

But if we look at the screenshot, that `MTIH4O2WFPWDvCso107p` document name is actually *inside* the `messages` collection, and before that is another ID. So if you want to just load that document you need:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .doc('chats/j701pWfp.../messages/MTIH4O2WFPWDvCso107p')
```

With `j701pWfp...` being the complete ID of the document under `chats`.

If you want to load all messages, that'd be:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('chats/j701pWfp.../messages')
```

Comment: Now it's returning a  "a collection path must point to a valid collection." error.

Comment: That makes sense. Since the path consists of 4 segments, it points to a document and not a collection. If you want to load all messages from the `chats/j701pWfp...`, you don't need that last ID.

Comment: Ah now I get it. Thanks!